# Ctools do not show up in pentaho UI

Tags: wget, pentaho, pentaho-ctools

I am using Pentaho CE 5 on windows. I would like to use CTools but I can't make them show up in the File -> New menu to use them.

Being behind a proxy, I can not use the Marketplace plugin, so I have tried a manual installation.

- First, I tried to use the ctools-installer.sh. I have run the following command line in cygwin (wget and unzip are installed):

./ctools-installer.sh -s /cygdrive/d/Users/[user]/Mes\ Programmes/pentaho/biserver-ce/pentaho-solutions/ -w /cygdrive/d/Users/[user]/Mes\ programmes/pentaho/biserver-ce/tomcat/webapps/pentaho/

The script starts, asks me what module I want to install, and begins the downloads.

For each module, I get an output like (set -x added to the script) :

> - echo -n 'Downloading CDF...' Downloading CDF...+ wget -q --no-check-certificate 'http://ci.analytical-labs.com/job/Webdetails-CDF-5-Release/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/bi-platform-v2-plugin/dist/*zip*/dist.zip'
>     -O .tmp/cdf/dist.zip SYSTEM_WGETRC = c:/progra~1/wget/etc/wgetrc syswgetrc = C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32/etc/wgetrc
> - '[' '!' -z '' ']'
> - rm -f .tmp/dist/marketplace.xml
> - unzip -o .tmp/cdf/dist.zip -d .tmp   End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not   a zipfile, or it
>     constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the   latter case
>     the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on   the last
>     disk(s) of this archive. unzip:  cannot find zipfile directory in
>     .tmp/cdf/dist.zip,
>         and cannot find .tmp/cdf/dist.zip.zip, period.
> - chmod -R u+rwx .tmp
> - echo Done Done

Then the script ends. I have seen [on this page (pentaho-bi-suite)](http://pentaho-bi-suite.blogspot.fr/2014/04/pentaho-c-tools-manual-installation-in.html) that it is the normal output. Nevertheless, it seems a bit strange to me and when I start my pentaho server (login: admin/password), I cannot see any new tools in the menus.

- After a look to a few other tutorials and the script itself, I have downloaded the .zip snapshots for every tool and unzipped them in the system directory of my pentaho server. Same result.

I would like to make the .sh works, what can I try or adjust ?

Thanks

**EDIT 05/06/2014**

I checked the dist.zip files dowloaded by the script and they are all empty. It seems that wget cannot fetch the zip files, and therefore the installation fails.
When I try to get any webpage through wget, it fails. I think it is because of the proxy.

Here is my .wgetrc file, located in my user's cygwin home folder:

> use_proxy=on
>
> http_proxy=http://[url]:[port]
>
> https_proxy=http://[url]:[port]
>
> proxy_user=[user]
>
> proxy_password=[password]

How could I make this work?

**EDIT 10/06/2014**

In the end, I have changed my network connection settings to bypass the proxy. It seems that there is an offline mode for the installer, so one can download all needed files on a proxy-free environment and then run the script offline.
I guess this is related with the -r option.

I consider this post solved, since it not a CTools issue anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I have changed my network connection settings to bypass the proxy. It seems that there is an offline mode for the installer, so one can download all needed files on a proxy-free environment and then run the script offline. I guess this is related with the -r option.

I consider this post solved, since it is not a CTools issue anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Difficult to identify the issue in the above procedure..
but you can refer [this blog](http://pedroalves-bi.blogspot.pt/2013/11/ctools-for-pentaho-50-is-available-cdf.html) he is key member of pentaho itself..

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will see what I get and come back here to give further information.

Answer (score 0):

You can manually install the components from http://www.webdetails.pt/ctools/ or if you have pentaho 5.1 or above, you add the following parameters to CATALINA_OPTS option (in start-pentaho.bat or start-pentaho.sh):
-Dhttp.proxyHost= -Dhttp.proxyPort= -Dhttp.nonProxyHosts="localhost|127.0.0.1|10.*.*.*"

http://docs.treasuredata.com/articles/pentaho-dataintegration#tips-how-can-i-use-pentaho-through-a-proxy